# local variable referenced before assignment / Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to design a counter which would be incremented each time an action is done. Something like this:

```
def action_on_accounts(self, accounts):
    for account in accounts[9:]: 
        try:
            self.browser.get(account)
            time.sleep(5)
            action_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(u'//button[contains(@class, "Heart")]').click()
            counter_var = self.count_actions(counter_var)
            print(counter_var)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            break

def count_actions(self, counter_var):
    return counter_var + 1

def main(self):

    counter_var = 0
    (...)
```

This is throwing a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter_var' referenced before assignment`

I have read that I have to declare `counter_var` as global inside function and did this:

```
def count_actions(self, counter_var):
    global counter_var
    return counter_var + 1
```

It was throwing `SyntaxError: name 'counter_var' is parameter and global error`.

So I tried this :

```
def count_actions(self):
    global counter_var
    return counter_var + 1
```

Calling it this way :

```
counter_var = self.count_actions()
print(counter_var)
```

And now I have `NameError: name 'counter_var' is not defined`....

Please assist

Comment: `counter_var` exists in your `count_actions`, but not in `action_on_accounts`. Use your `global` there

Comment: You can't reference `counter_var` on the right-hand side of an assignment before you've initialized it in the relevant scope: `counter_var = self.count_actions(counter_var)`. Move `counter_car = 0` into `action_on_accounts()` function and return it to main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider defining `counter_var` as an attribute: `self.counter_var`. It'll be accessible throughout your class (assuming that's what's going on). You won't have to provide it explicitly as an argument in your functions/methods and no need to worry about global variables.

```
def action_on_accounts(self, accounts):
    for account in accounts[9:]: 
        try:
            self.browser.get(account)
            time.sleep(5)
            action_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(u'//button[contains(@class, "Heart")]').click()
            self.count_actions()
            print(self.counter_var)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            break

def count_actions(self):
    self.counter_var += 1

def main(self):

    self.counter_var = 0
    (...)
```

You'll probably want to initialize `self.counter_var` with your class however.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it. No global variables, no hidden magic.

Comment: thanks for this solution it works as well ! And also It permits not to use global variables (I've read that it wasnt good to use ? )

Comment: Global variables often lead to something called spaghetti code. Basically global variables allow you to code without structure. And since you can do this you will do this by accident (eventually). Then a few days pass and no one will be able to read / understand your code. Therefore they are kind of a programming sin. Use them if you must or if everything else is even worse.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, simpler solution is to use python's built-in enumerate(); It exists so we don't have to make our own functions. You can then set the count equal to a global variable declared outside your functions

So the code would look like this:

```
counter_var = 0
def action_on_accounts(self, accounts):
    for count, account in enumerate(accounts[9:]): 
            global counter_var
            counter_var = count
            print(counter_var)

def main(self):
    global counter_var
    counter_var = 0
    (...)
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution !

Comment: This will reset your counter on every call to `action_on_accounts`, which might be fine for you. Not what you had originally though. And to echo advice in other comments, I would seriously consider if you need to use global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really want to use a global variable (which I advice against) you can do it with the `global` keyword. You need that keyword to declare the variable. Example:

```
def action_on_accounts():
    global counter_var #declare the variable
    counter_var = count_actions(counter_var)
    print(counter_var)

def count_actions(cv):
    global counter_var  #you do not have to declare the variable here since we are theoretically in the right scope
    print(counter_var) #just to check that is global
    return cv + 1 #no need to declare since it is a parameter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    counter_var = 0
    action_on_accounts() #1
    action_on_accounts() #2
    print(counter_var) #will return 2
```

I tested this in the IPython console (Python 3.6).

However I strongly recommend that you use attributes of classes to do the same effect (as in use self not global). Global variables may create bad code.